# How are private keys stored on disk?

Tags: encryption

I have a public and secret key pair in my .ssh folder. How is the secret key being stored on disk? What I mean is .. Is it possible for someone to hack into my computer, steal the secret key and use it to decrypt all my messages which were encrypted with my public key?

Secondly, gpg requires a password to make use of the secret key. Does it not mean that someone can brute force the password and use the secret key anyways? After all, passwords are never as secure as secret keys ..

Or does the computer do some magic behind the scenes so that brute forcing the password that protects the secret key is simply impossible?

Comment: I think the 'magic' you refer to is a password-based-key-derivation-function such as [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or, ideally, [Scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt). It's a function that derives a cryptographic key from a password, and is computationally expensive to the point that brute-force attacks become infeasible.

Comment: OpenSSH uses an expensive key derivation function to turn your password into an appropriate symmetric key for encrypting your private SSH key. This will slow down a brute force attack considerably, but the difficulty is still proportional to the complexity of your passphrase. That said, if an attacker gains access to your machine, it's already game over; they can simply wait for you to enter your passphrase and capture it.

Comment: @StephenTouset I might be wrong, but I thought the OpenSSH KDF was pretty bad. Like 1000 rounds of PBKDF2 or something. They recently added bcrypt, though! \o/

Comment: @StephenTouset I Googled around. Before they added bcrypt in 6.5, it was one "round" of salted MD5! Oh my gods! (It was possible to use other tools to generate key files with a better KDF, and OpenSSH would read them fine, though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How is the secret key being stored on disk?

Like any other file is stored on disk.

> Is it possible for someone to hack into my computer, steal the secret key and use it to decrypt all my messages which were encrypted with my public key?

Yes. Your private key is VERY important for this reason.

> Does it not mean that someone can brute force the password and use the secret key anyways?

Yes, they can. Using a weak password to protect your private key will not guarantee you much security if your private key should fall into the wrong hands.

When it comes to public/private key cryptography, there is no understating how private your private key should be.

Answer (score 4):

To add Matt and James's answers, OpenSSL allows you to use passphrases, which I highly recommend. This is arguably more secure than a password as it theoretically adds more entropy (how many possibilities exist), see http://xkcd.com/936/.

I say "arguably" and "theoretically" as it's still perfectly possible to bungle this using weak passphrases. A recent study showed it was possible to brute force passphrases using common terms. http://www.jbonneau.com/doc/BS12-USEC-passphrase_linguistics.pdf

My current practice is generating long strings of around 100 alphanumeric and symbol characters and storing them in LastPass. This means my private key passphrases don't have to mean anything to me, or be memorable at all but has the down side that if some were to work out my LastPass passphrase *and* get my private key, they'd be able to open it.

Comment: Haha, a chain of answers adding to each other. 100 characters is rather a lot -- assuming an alphabet of 64 characters, that's *600 bits*. I wouldn't use a password longer than 128 bits (22 characters).

Comment: If you don't need to remember it or type it, what would be the down side to having 100 characters... or more?

Comment: @DanielM - Multitude of sites which have password limit set to 16, 30, 65 or other small values. Since I started using KeePass I generate 128 character passwords but I've already encountered a good number of sites which have upper limit on password length.

Answer (score 3):

To add two things on top of James Mishra's excellent answer:

> How is the secret key being stored on disk? What I mean is ..

OpenSSH supports optionally encrypting your private key with a password. With a sufficiently good password, it won't be possible to decrypt your key, even if an adversary has the file.

> Is it possible for someone to hack into my computer, steal the secret key and use it to decrypt all my messages which were encrypted with my public key?

SSH uses [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy), so they will not be able to decrypt your past communications. They will be able to impersonate you and obviously cause lots of other trouble.